# Way to persist object in db using Hibernate save method in for loop

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, rest

I am trying to add multiple employee objects in the db but only the last object is getting added in the db.
and I want to use loop only to add multiple objects.

Following is the code.
(Note - I just started leaning spring so I request you to please elaborate the answer)

@PostMapping("/employees")

```
public Employee addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
    employeeService.save(employee);
    return employee;
}
```

@Service

public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void save(Employee employee) {
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        Employee emp = getDummyEmployee(employee,i);
        employee = emp;
        employeeDao.save(employee);
        System.out.println("After save----"+emp);
    }
}

private Employee getDummyEmployee(Employee emp,int i) {
    emp.setFirstName(emp.getFirstName().concat(""+i));
    emp.setLastName(emp.getLastName().concat(""+i)); 
    emp.setEmail(emp.getEmail().concat(""+i));
    return emp;
}
```

}

@Repository

public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO{

private EntityManager entityManager;

```
@Autowired
public EmployeeDAOImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

@Override
public void save(Employee employee) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // get current hibernate session
    Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

    currentSession.save(employee);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate treat instances as manageds entityes, if you change the same instance hibernate will save its value to the database overriding the old values.

The solution is create a new instance of the model for every entry.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void save(Employee employee) {
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        Employee emp = getDummyEmployee(employee,i);
        employee = emp;
        employeeDao.save(emp);
        System.out.println("After save----"+emp);
    }
}

private Employee getDummyEmployee(Employee other, int i) {
    Emplyee emp = new Employe();
    emp.setFirstName(other.getFirstName().concat(""+i));
    emp.setLastName(other.getLastName().concat(""+i)); 
    emp.setEmail(other.getEmail().concat(""+i));
    return emp;
}
```

Comment: Hi Marcos,
I am creating new instance in getDummyEmployee() method.

Comment: You are not, you are filling the attributes from another previosuly created instance of Employee and assigning the same instance to a new variable. Test my code and you will see the difference.

Comment: The solution is the ```new```keyword at   ```Emplyee emp = new Employe();```